# My Loop seems to be broken

Tags: c++, loops

My loop is not printting its 6th entry.

It should display `0    4    0` on the line, but it just skips it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int NUMPLANTTYPES = 7;

int main()
{
    double PlantNumbers[NUMPLANTTYPES] = {25, 56, 44, 120, 16, 0, 15};
    int PotSize[NUMPLANTTYPES] = {3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
    double TotalCosts[NUMPLANTTYPES] = { 10, 10, 3.5, 6.99, 10, 10, 3.5 };

    cout << "PlantSold\t PotSize\tTotalCosts " << endl;
    for (int MAXSALES = 0; MAXSALES < 7; MAXSALES++)
    {
        if (PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] > 8) 
        {
            float TotalCost = (PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] * TotalCosts[MAXSALES]);

            cout << PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] << "\t\t " << PotSize[MAXSALES] << "\t\t  " << TotalCost << endl;
        }
    }

    int a;
    cin >> a;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you think `if (PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] > 8) ` does ?

Comment: Please use debugger!

Comment: @abelenky that variable is declared: `float TotalCost = (PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] * TotalCosts[MAXSALES]);`

Comment: How do you get `0 4 0`?? IF that line were to run, (and it does not because of the if-statement), it would output `0 4 10`.

Comment: How can `PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] > 8` be true when the for loop limits the variable to `MAXSALES < 7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My loop won't print its 6th entry, any help?

Yep, because `PlantNumbers[5]` equals 0 and because of:

```
    if (PlantNumbers[MAXSALES] > 8)
```